# Is it true that $\bigcap_i N_i \cap K = 1$, then $N_j \cap K = 1$ for some $j$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have a question that should be simple, but it's confusing me.

> Suppose that we have $H,K$ subgroups of $G$ with $H \cap K = 1$. If $H = \bigcap_{i \in I} N_i$ where $N_i$ are subgroups and and $I$ is some set of index, then can we ensure that
> $$N_j \cap K = 1$$
> for some $j$?

Intuitively, it seems true but I'm not sure. For example, perhaps there is some $a_i \in N_i \cap K$ for every $i$ with $a_i \neq a_j$ for $i \neq j$ such that it not contradicts $H \cap K = 1$. Also, if we suppose $K$ finite then I think the question holds. But I want to know, in the case it does not holds in general, what is the "weaker" hypothesis that we can ask for the result holds?

Comment: $N_1=\sqrt 2 \mathbb Z, N_2=\sqrt 3 \mathbb Z, H=\{0\}, K=\sqrt 3 \mathbb Z$ in $(\mathbb R,+)$.

Comment: Let $G=S_3$ be a group of permutations of degree 3.
Let $K=G$, $H=1$, $N_1=\langle(12)\rangle$, $N_2=\langle(13)\rangle$, $N_3=\langle(123)\rangle$ (but the first two subgroups are sufficient). 
Clearly, $H=N_1\cap N_2\cap N_3$, but $K\cap N_i=N_i\neq 1$ for each $i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\Z{\mathbb Z}$ In $\Z$ the subgroups $2\Z, 3\Z, 4\Z, \dots$ have trivial intersection with $K=\Z$, but no one of them has that property. Note that all these are distinct, contradicting a claim in the accepted answer.